# Multiple left joins vs Promise.all

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js, mariadb, es6-promise

I have a nodejs app and a mariaDB (Mysql) database connected to it where data is stored. I have written a query which I am executing asynchronously and awaiting it:

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM
    table t1
        LEFT JOIN
    table t3 ON t1.token = t3.token
        LEFT JOIN   
    table t2 ON t1.token = t2.token
        LEFT JOIN
    table t4 ON t1.token = t4.token
WHERE
    t1.token = 'abcd'
        AND (t3.box_type = 1
        OR t3.box_type IS NULL);
```

I have `token` column as an indexed column and it is **not unique**. Is it possible that when I split these queries in multiple functions and then promisify all of them together, then will it be faster? Below is the sample code that I am talking about and would like to compare:

```
getDataFromT1: async (token) => {
        let query = `SELECT * FROM table1 where token = '${token}'`;
        return mysqlDb.queryAsync(query);
}

getDataFromT2: async (token) => {
        let query = `SELECT * FROM table2 where token = '${token}'`;
        return mysqlDb.queryAsync(query);
}

getDataFromT3: async (token) => {
        let query = `SELECT * FROM table3 where token = '${token}' where box_type = 1 OR box_type IS NULL`;
        return mysqlDb.queryAsync(query);
}
getDataFromT4: async (token) => {
        let query = `SELECT * FROM table4 where token = '${token}'`;
        return mysqlDb.queryAsync(query);
}

const [t1Response, t2Response, t3Response, t4Response] = await Promise.all([getDataFromT1('abcd'),getDataFromT2('abcd'),getDataFromT3('abcd'),getDataFromT4('abcd')]);
```

This is some additional information which might help in answering:

**table1** has **110K** records, **table2** has **76K** records, **table3** has **445K** records and **table4** has **35K** records

Comment: The question is too broad. Yes, it's always possible. You can check whether it's so

Comment: I have tried to minimise it as possible as I can. However, you can still tell me what do you think on this? What are the possible scenarios?

Comment: can you use `console.time()` and share the results

Comment: Nobody can answer timing questions but *you yourself* doing a benchmark of both in *your environment*

Comment: Possible scenarios are that either one of them performs better than another, but this may change under load, or not. Since DB is a likely bottleneck I expect that 1 is preferable in general but only you can confirm which one is better in your case. 2 may be better if you cache results